# findViewById returning null when using Android's resource overlays mechanism to overlay layout files

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I have an existing layout A in the AOSP code that I would like to modify, but instead of directly modifying this layout A, I would like to define a new layout B that overlays layout A to avoid modifying the original layout.

The directory structure to layout B in the overlay directory matches the directory structure of layout A and the overlay directory is already defined in the make file like this

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS := <my-overlay-directory>
```

In layout A, some views are defined with some associated ids. These ids are referenced in a Java source file like this

```
object.setContentView(contentView);

...

final View myView1 = object.findViewById(R.id.someViewId1);
final View myView2 = myView1.findViewById(R.id.someViewId2);
```

In the new layout B, the views are defined the exact same way as in layout A with the same ids. However, during runtime I am seeing a NullPointerException from calling myView1.findViewById(R.id.someViewId2), which indicates that myView1 is null. Without layout B in the overlay directory, the original code works fine, but the exception appears when the layout gets overlaid. This leads me to believe that findViewById is not finding the view correctly when overlaying layout files. Does anyone know why findViewById is returning null and whether it is possible to overlay layout files?

Comment: Any chance the ids are not actually the same? That is, maybe one is `android.R.id.someViewId1` while the other is `com.yourpackage.R.id.someViewId1`.

Comment: Could you explain how one would be able to tell? The resource I am overlaying is under framework core.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the overlaying system, but presumably there is some layout.xml file in the framework core. Any id used in that layout file will necessarily be an `android.R` / `@android:id/` id. Then there's the file in your project. If you are writing `@+id/someViewId1`, then that will be packaged with your app's resources, and therefore will be a different id than the one in the framework. Perhaps you could replace it with `@android:id/someViewId1`, and then in code make sure you're using `android.R.id.someViewId1`.

Comment: That's exactly what your earlier comment led me to do and it seems to be working now!

Comment: So, could you explain how did you fix it?